# Can i skip the same values of columns postgresql

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I have this query  `SELECT complate_set FROM info_about_cars WHERE complate_set ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%1%', '%4%', '%TSI%', '%4motion%']);` many values of column in my table has the same value. Can I skip the same value of column?

```
{ complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4 (312.AXD1A)' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
  { complate_set: '1.4' },
```

but i want

```
{ complate_set: '1.4' },
{ complate_set: '1.4 (312.AXD1A)' },
```

Comment: What do you mean by " ілшз the same value"?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and sample output of what you want?

Comment: @Dai i have edited

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: So `complate_set` is a `jsonb` or `json` column? Or do you want the output to be converted to a JSON structure?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT have worked.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name complate_set is text

Comment: So you want the output converted to JSON?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I do not. I wanted skip all the same values of column, without repeats. In examples are unparsed rows.